# How to solve this issue of Hardcoded string?

Tags: android

[I18N] Hardcoded string "Happy Birthday Debashish", should use @string resource less... (Ctrl+F1)

Hardcoding text attributes directly in layout files is bad for several 
        reasons:  * When creating configuration variations (for example for landscape or 
        portrait)you have to repeat the actual text (and keep it up to date when 
        making changes)  * The application cannot be translated to other languages by
        just adding new translations for existing string resources.  In Android Studio 
       and Eclipse there are quickfixes to automatically extract this hardcoded string 
        into a resource lookup.

[image]

Comment: That's not an error. It's just a `warning`. It's a best practice to store your strings as separate resource files.

Comment: How much questions u will post here until  learn android ? put some effort for surfing and always that would be preferable way for a beginner. See this http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String

Comment: Justifying my Downvote for this question: Android Studio will always point a "red exclamation mark" signal in your Layout File or in your Java Class, when something is wrong with some of your declarations. For Warnings, as this one, Android Studio will put a "yellow tag". Please, look for some Android Tutorials or maybe the official documentation that presents the basics of Android Studio IDE (https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html). Regards, my friend.

Answer (score 20):

Ths is not an error but a warning. As a general rule, you should never use hard-coded strings in your layout but always use string resources instead (which means that all the strings are stored in one separate file where they are easily changeable for different languages and so on).

To convert a hard-coded string into a string resource:

- Put the curser on the hard coded string;
- Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>;
- Enter a name for your ressource;
- Click OK.

After doing this the warning will be gone.

Comment: Option + Enter for Mac

Answer (score 9):

```
This is just a warning.
Define your string in string.xml file
```

Happy Birthday Debashish

```
and in textView use this string as

 <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string_name"
        />
```

Answer (score 8):

This is only a warning. The function will still work as intended. It is just recommended to place your text in the `strings.xml` file. This makes future changes much simpler and is easier to reference across multiple pages.

First, place the `<string>` element in `values/strings.xml` like this:

```html
<string name="your_string_name">Happy Birthday Debashish</string>
```

Then, you can reference the `string` in the `.xml` file as follows:

```html
<TextView
        android:text="@strings/your_string_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Again, it is not required to do it in this method. It just makes things simpler to manage and change in the future if needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        tools:text="Happy Birthday Debashish" />
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the 2019 version. Go to the strings.xml and Add this in to it

```
<string name="Your text">Your Text</string>
```

Or

In the warning it has the **Fix** button you can click it for fix